# Activerecord query with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I need to find all the records which contains the given sub-string(art), and the condition is the given substring is either a complete word within the string or the start of any word within the string.

Sample data. Program

```
id | name
-----------
10 | Report of Quarter 1
11 | The Art Program
12 | The Artificial Program
```

From the above data, I must be able to get the record numbers 11 and 12 but not 10.

I am trying like this

`Program.where("name ~* ?",'art\b')`
but it's not working

I have also tried with
`Program.where("regexp_match(name, ?)",'/art\b/i')`
this too is not working

any help is really appreciable. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED

I guess you are using Postgres since you gave an example with regexp_match

Try `Program.where("name ~* ?",'\mart')` :)

You can see hidden in the Postgres docs ("Regular Expression Escapes" section) that `\b` means "backspace, as in C" whereas `\m` "matches only at the beginning of a word"

Comment: Thanks for highlighting Escapes, `\M` will matches at the EOW but my requirement is to match with the starting of the word. so in my case I have to change the expression like `Program.where("name ~* ?",'\mart')`

Comment: indeed :) edited my answer to match this